# How to disable Office key keyboard shortcut opening Office app?

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

I found that some of my keyboard shortcuts somehow trigger open office 365 welcome window. I'm a heavy autohotkey user and it looks like it have something to do with alt+shift. I tried to remove office alltogether, but then new window in chrome spawns on keyboard shortcut suggesting me to buy office. Can I remove it somehow?

P.S. Here's the link to popup: https://www.office.com/?from=OfficeKey
As you can see, from option is set to "OfficeKey". What is this OfficeKey then and how to change it or better completely remove?

P.P.S. As described here: https://www.theverge.com/2019/6/18/18683333/microsoft-office-key-keyboards-support it is added recently, and it looks like the reason in that I'm on developers edition of windows 10 with latest updates.

Here's the screenshot of browser popup:
[image]

Comment: Is it possible that you have installed Office trial and now cannot get rid of the request for buying a serial?

Comment: no, its only triggered when I press specific keboard shortcuts like alt + shift + l for some reason

Comment: Please add a screenshot of that windows.

Comment: @harrymc added in description.

Comment: Alt+shift is used for switching input languages. If you only have one input language you can disable it.

Comment: @harrymc How is this corresponds to my question? I have only one language and prior to last windows update had no issue with language switching. Not even touching that its not language switching, its office welcome window/popup.

Comment: Then what are you using  alt+shift for? If this is caused by some startup product: (1) See if this is happening while booting in Safe mode, and if not then (2) Use [Autoruns](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/autoruns) to disable/re-enable startup products in bunches until you find the one.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Just upgraded to Windows 1903 and hit this myself, seems Microsoft decided to assign the keyboard shortcut for the new Office App to Win+Ctrl+Alt+Shift! (aka HYPR key combination for QMK users)

Changing the open command for this keyboard shortcut to rundll32 resolved the issue for me.  Using an elevated cmd, run the following command:

```
    REG ADD HKCU\Software\Classes\ms-officeapp\Shell\Open\Command /t REG_SZ /d rundll32
```

Comment: This did not work for me. For example, pressing Win+Ctrl+Alt+Shift+L still takes me to LinkedIn.

Comment: @aardvarkk That is only to disable the base shortcut. You need to use OfficeKeyFix (linked in another answer) to remap the other Office Key shortcuts.

Answer (score 8):

[jfrmilner's answer](https://superuser.com/a/1484332/160219) works, but doesn't disable the application-specific hotkeys.

[How to Remap the Office Key on Your Keyboard](https://www.howtogeek.com/445318/how-to-remap-the-office-key-on-your-keyboard/).

[OfficeKeyFix](https://github.com/anthonyheddings/OfficeKeyFix)-

It involves restarting Explorer, so it's not pretty, but it is a fix.

Comment: Anthony appears to have deleted their GitHub profile. The code was forked and unmodified here: https://github.com/acook/OfficeKeyFix

Comment: It's kinda ironic how the most used OS in the world works against professionals in any possible capacity.

Comment: @PaulMEdwards On the GitHub page it says 'You'll need to compile the script into a binary,' — what on Earth does that mean? I've tried Googling thoroughly... Love it when people make things super cryptic for us non-experts in these sorts of areas!

Comment: @Vladimir the file in that repository is C++ program code (referred to as a script). It must be compiled with a C++ compiler to be used. The same is true of the newer repository mentioned at the link I shared, which is: https://github.com/jorystewart/OfficeKeyFix

Comment: @Vladimir here is a walkthrough from Microsoft on how to compile C++ programs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/walkthrough-compiling-a-native-cpp-program-on-the-command-line?view=msvc-170

Comment: @PaulMEdwards thank you, I'll check this out! Been using ExplorerPatcher in the meanwhile.

Answer (score 2):

For AHK:

```
^!+LWin::send {Blind}{vk07}
```

It keeps the OfficeKey + letter hotkeys in place. You can add your own:

```
^!+#m::run explorer.exe shell:AppsFolder\microsoft.windowscommunicationsapps_8wekyb3d8bbwe!microsoft.windowslive.mail
^!+#c::run explorer.exe shell:AppsFolder\microsoft.windowscommunicationsapps_8wekyb3d8bbwe!microsoft.windowslive.calendar
```

If you have installed the Microsoft Office app from the Microsoft Store, this app will open instead of the website. If you still want to be able to use the app sometimes and it's installed, you can map it to OfficeKey + Enter for example:

```
^!+#Enter::run explorer.exe shell:AppsFolder\Microsoft.MicrosoftOfficeHub_8wekyb3d8bbwe!Microsoft.MicrosoftOfficeHub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [hyperenable](https://github.com/midrare/hyperenable). It's an improved version based on OfficeKeyFix. (No console window flash, no explorer restart, no hardcoded 4s delay.)

*Disclaimer: I'm the author.*

Comment: This app is my last hope, as all other answers here are not working for me ;) But, I get an error installing it: `(...) Linking hyperenable.exe
cl -nologo -std:c++20 -EHs -EHc -O2 pipe.obj squatter.obj wincon.obj yaml.obj main.obj -link -nologo -subsystem:windows user32.lib shell32.lib ole32.lib -out:hyperenable.exe
make[1]: Leaving directory 'c:/Users/myuser/Downloads/hyperenable-master/src'
Invalid switch - /-I
make: *** [Makefile:11: src] Error 4` I get this both when running the `make` command in powershell and in developer command prompt. I'll open a github issue for your convenience.

Comment: Sorry, false alarm. The error message was real, but not critical and the binary was built just fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can set it to any command by adding the following subkeys to:

```
Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\ms-officeapp\shell\open\command
```

and changing the string value to any command or path you use often or leave it empty

Comment: Did you forgot the "following subkeys"?

Answer (score -3):

- locate OneDrive icon somewhere
- right click item
- "Settings"
- "Office" tab
- uncheck "Use Office applications to sync Office files that I open"

:)

[image]

Comment: What does this have to do with the Office key?