# Pressing Ctrl+Alt+Shift+Win key combination installs Microsoft OfficeHub app package to a system and launches it

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-office, hotkeys, windows-key

How to disable this behavior?

I tried to uninstall from "Add or remove program", after this office hub disappear from list of installed apps, but if I press buttons from the subj. It just come back and launches the office hub again.

I have win10 with the latest updates from stable channel.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to disable Office key keyboard shortcut opening Office app?](https://superuser.com/questions/1455857/how-to-disable-office-key-keyboard-shortcut-opening-office-app)

Comment: Have no idea, I have "fixed" it with migrating to linux from windows ;)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this [page](https://windowsreport.com/remove-my-office-windows-10/#1)

Maybe you can delete the app with powershell.

Scroll down a little to  **2: Uninstall My Office with a PowerShell**

You can find Windows Powershell (this is for Windows 8) at the following address :

```
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\System Tools\Windows PowerShell.lnk
```

Run **Windows PowerShell.lnk** as **Administrator**

The provided command at the site is :

```
Get-AppxPackage *officehub* | Remove-AppxPackage
```

Good luck

Comment: Same result - after successful uninstall if I press alt ctrl shift win it installs in a second and launches :(