# Disable Windows's built-in keyboard shortcut to open LinkedIn?

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts

I recently learned that pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> on Windows opens LinkedIn in your default web browser.

Why does this happen? What application catches the keyboard shortcut? I want to turn it off.

Comment: That does not happen here. Are you using Linkedin?

Comment: See https://superuser.com/questions/1455857/how-to-disable-office-key-keyboard-shortcut-opening-office-app

Comment: @John, yes, it seems to be a long-standing issue, related to https://superuser.com/questions/1455857/how-to-disable-office-key-keyboard-shortcut-opening-office-app .

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be a duplicate of [How to disable Office key keyboard shortcut opening Office app?](https://superuser.com/questions/1455857/how-to-disable-office-key-keyboard-shortcut-opening-office-app), but deserves more explanation:

## Explicating the Issue

###### skip to end for a *somewhat impractical* work-around.

Interesting! I thought that might be *browser* dependent,  but it's not; evidently it's baked into Windows (as tested on version 22H2, build 19045.3693)!

With Firefox, my default browser open, I also opened Brave browser. While Brave was *focused*, pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Windows</kbd><kbd>L</kbd> sets focus to Firefox (i.e., the default browser) and opens LinkedIn.

Nastier, using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Windows</kbd> [hereafter referred to as *combo*]+<kbd>W</kbd> opens MS account, *combo*+<kbd>T</kbd> opens MS Teams, and **just** *combo* keys opens the following: https://www.microsoft365.com/?from=OfficeKey . **N.B.** note the URL query string: **?from=OfficeKey**. Others I've found: *combo*+<kbd>Y</kbd> -> Yammer, *combo*+O -> Outlook, *combo*+<kbd>D</kbd> -> OneDrive, and, as Tom Lehrer said, "There may be many others but they haven't been discavahd."

## *A Somewhat Impractical* Workaround

Using [Clavier+](https://gryder.org/software/clavier-plus/?lang=en), a keyboard shortcut/macro utility similar to [AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/), I was able to set the unused key *combo*+<kbd>Q</kbd> to open another application. (Setting it directly to  *combo*+<kbd>L</kbd> could not be done, because attempting to enter that shortcut instead opened a browser to LinkedIn.)

The .ini file was edited, replacing <kbd>Q</kbd> with <kbd>L</kbd>. However, after restarting *Clavier+*, I found Windows intercepted that key combo, opening LinkedIn, *before Clavier+*.

However, I then used Russinovich's [Process Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer) to

- Close all open instances of *Explorer.exe*,
- Restart *Clavier+*,
- And then run a new instance of *Explorer*.

***Voila!*** *Combo*+<kbd>L</kbd> now opens an alternate application. There are some drawbacks to this approach, though.

- It required killing and restarting multiple applications after Windows is up and running -- not just at the start of boot.
- It broke User Access Control: There is no UAC dialog when starting an app as Administrator; the app runs immediately.
- Items that should have been in the Taskbar disappeared.

## Executive Summary

Windows 10, at least for v. 22H2, b. 19045.3693,has baked-in keyboard shortcuts to proprietary Microsoft products such as Office and to MS subsidiaries, such as LinkedIn. These are embedded at such a low level in the Windows OS that it is difficult to intercept or bypass them.

If someone would try that workaround with [AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/) or an [alternative](https://alternativeto.net/software/autohotkey/), **please** comment below or edit this excessively long "answer".

There **might** be a workaround by [Anthony Heddings](https://github.com/acook/OfficeKeyFix/blob/master/OfficeKeyFix.cpp), but one would have to download the C++ code and compile it (my guess is that the executable is not distributed because it might be identified as malware by Windows *Defender* ;-), and install it as directed.

###### <sub>*sigh*  Now to log off Windows and back on to get it working "normally"...</sub>